# Install OpenMPI on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package, openmpi, installation-package, ubuntu-17.10

I am using the following command for OpenMPI installation on Ubuntu 17.10:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-common openssh-client openssh-server libopenmpi1.3 libopenmpi-dbg libopenmpi-dev.
```

However, I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libopenmpi1.3
```

I wanted to know how to fix this. Alternatively,I am open to installing openmpi differently if anyone knows another way of doing it.

Comment: why do you want to install `libopenmpi1.3` ? could you simply let `openmpi-bin` and `libopenmpi-dev` automatically install their dependencies ?

Answer (score 5):

`apt-get install libopenmpi1.10` would work.